# Tengo un problema al momento de añadir un objeto a una lista (WPF c#)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017

resulta que estoy haciendo un mantenedor, que tiene 2 clases: Cliente y contrato. El contrato tiene un Cliente. Pero al momento de agregarlo falla y me da el error:

"referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto "

Esta es mi clase cliente:

```
public class Clientes
    {

        public string rut { get; set; }
        public string razonsocial { get; set; }
        public string direccion { get; set; }
        public string telefono { get; set; }
        public string actividad  { get; set; }
        public string tipo { get; set; }



        public Clientes()
        {
            this.Init();

        }

        private void Init()
        {
            rut = string.Empty;
            razonsocial = string.Empty;
            direccion = string.Empty;
            telefono = string.Empty;
            actividad = string.Empty;
            tipo = string.Empty;

        }


    }
}
```

y esta es mi clase contrato:

```
 public class Contratos
    {
        public string nrocontrato { get; set; }
        public string fechaCreacion { get; set; }
        public string  FechaTermino { get; set; }
        public string Eventoinicio { get; set; }
        public string Eventotermino{ get; set; }
        public string Direccion { get; set; }
        public string Vigencia { get; set; }
        public string Observaciones { get; set; }
        public Clientes cliente { get; set; }


        public Contratos()
        {
            this.Init();
        }

        private void Init()
        {
            nrocontrato = string.Empty;




        }





    }
}
```

La creación de ambas listas están en mi ventana WPF principal:

```
public static List<Clientes> lista = new List<Clientes>();
public static List<Contratos> listacontratos = new List<Contratos>();
```

Entonces añado un cliente en mi ventana añadir cliente y no da problemas.
Luego en mi ventana añadir contrato si tengo problemas al momento de añadir un contrato:

```
private void Btb_agreg_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {     
            Clientes cli = MainWindow.lista.First(c => c.rut == txt_rutclia.Text);
            Contratos contr = new Contratos();

                contr.cliente.rut = cli.rut;
                contr.nrocontrato = txt_numero.Text;
                contr.fechaCreacion = DateTime.Today.ToString();             
                contr.Eventoinicio = dp_eveninicio.Text;
                contr.Eventotermino = dp_termino.Text;
                contr.Direccion = txt_direeve.Text;


                MainWindow.listacontratos.Add(contr);
                MessageBox.Show("El contrato a sido agregado exitosamente");
```

El error "referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto " me marca especificamente en:
contr.cliente.rut = cli.rut;

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: No estás inicializando tu cliente y si buscas en una lista a través de LINQ y no encuentra lo que buscas te devolverá un null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando creas una nueva instancia de `Contratos`, ni el constructor ni el método `Init` inicializan el objeto `Clientes`.

Por eso, cuando accedes al objeto `clientes` en la expresión `contr.cliente.rut = cli.rut` justo después de crear una instancia de `Contratos`, la propiedad `clientes` es `null`, por defecto.

En el constructor de `Contratos` deberías también inicializar el objeto `Clientes`.

```
public Contratos()
{
    Init();
    cliente = new Clientes();
}
```

O en el método, `Init`, como prefieras.

Comment: Respuesta perfecta, me funciono inmediatamente. Gracias !!!